# EmptyDataTemplate still shows message even if records found

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I was wondering if any one could shed some light on  property in the GridView.  As far as I know,  if no records are found, the text message inside 
 will be displayed, when the GridView control is bound to data.   Actually, it’s working fine, but it works even if the record is found, too.

Currently, the datagridview is like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNomineeSearchResults" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ind_cst_key"
AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" 
    OnSelectedIndexChanging="gvNomineeSearchResults_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCreated="gvNomineeSearchResults_RowCreated" 
    CssClass="selectedItems nominee" Width="100%" Caption="Search Results">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="lastname" HeaderText="Last Name" NullDisplayText="&nbsp;" /> 
    <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="First Name" NullDisplayText="&nbsp;" /> 
</Columns>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <p>Your search did not return any active AIAA Associate Fellows or did not find an email address on file for the individual you are searching for.</p>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

Any idea why the message is still showing even if records are found ?

Comment: Are you postive the gridview is being databound to something and that data actually has something in it, can you post some of that code

Comment: another test would be to bind it to a temporary list that you create with a few elements in it and see if that returns anything'

Answer (score 0):

Just Check the condition its correctly working or not.

Check the condition Gridview while Binding.

```
if(Dataset1.Items.count>0)
{
//Put your codes Here
}
```

Before Binding a Data to the Gridview Clear the Gridview Items.

```
Gridview1.Items.Clear();
```

Hope this may helpful....